# Phase difference in a standing wave?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength

What would the phase difference between P and Q be?
I assumed that because they are 1/4 of a wavelength apart, it would be Pi/2,  but supposedly the difference is 0.

[image]

Comment: The phase difference is zero.

Comment: @KV18 but why is that?

Comment: Have a look at this [simulation](https://www.walter-fendt.de/html5/phen/standingwavereflection_en.htm) and observe what is happening to the particles between nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $P$ and $Q$ have the same amplitudes at the *same time*. That is because the combining waves have no phase difference between them at that point.

Comment: Right so in a standing wave points like that have 0 phase difference. I see

Comment: @Karthik Is it possible to describe that in terms of equations? I have been really really curious about that but couldn't find answer. The equation is the product of $\cos \omega t$ and $\sin kx$ so I don't know which argument to take as a phase difference. Actually I tried out both but neither seems to give a correct answer. I am finding the analogous version of the phase difference $\phi = k\Delta x + \omega \Delta t$ in a travelling wave.